# Twitter like "characters left" function problems in C: How to prevent it from going to the next line?

Tags: c, twitter, character, project, getch

Like my last question, this concerns my school project. I have to do a "twitter like" program in C and i'm having a small layout problem. **Please, keep in mind that i'm aware that this code is not optimized and i am first "playing around" to get the basics working.**

Here is the function i'm having trouble with (don't pay attention to the printf's with all the \b, its only temporary and very messy):

```
printf("Saisissez votre message (%d caracteres max):",DIM_MSG); //Message entry character by character
        //Boucle de saisie de message caractere par caractere
        while((temptweet=getch()) != '\r' )
        {
            if ( temptweet == '\b' ) {
                if( i>0 ){
                    printf ( "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b", ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ',' ');
                }
                if ( i != 0) {
                    printf ( "\b%c\b", ' ' );
                    i--;
                    printf(" %03d / %d",i,DIM_MSG); //Shows the remaining chracters left
                }

            }
            else if (i<DIM_MSG){
                flag=0;
                if(i!=0){
                    printf ( "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b%c\b", ' ' );
                }
                tweet[i] = (char)temptweet;
                printf("%c",tweet[i]);
                if(i>=(DIM_MSG-WARN)){Color(12,0);}
                printf(" %03d / %d",i+1,DIM_MSG);
                if(i>=(DIM_MSG-WARN)){Color(7,0);}
                i++;
            }
            if( i==0 && flag!=1){
                    printf ( "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b", ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ',' ',' ');
                    flag=1;
            }
        }
        tweet[i]='\0';
```

This function lets the user enter a message and shows the user how many characters are left for him to type (the DIM_MSG constant is this size). Basically, as the user types it shows the number of characters written on the right side of the text (kind of like twitter at the bottom of the textbox).

The issue i'm having is that when you type something long and reach the side of the command window, it "breaks" and goes to the next line and i end up with something like this in the window:

```
Saisissez votre message (140 caracteres max):testtesttesttesttesttestt 025 / 140
esttesttesttetstesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttes 095 / 140
ttest 100 / 140
```

What's bothering me is that when you delete text (backspace key or '\b' ), it stops at the line you are at. If you look at the example, you would be able to delete "ttest" at the last line and then you would be stuck (although the counter would still go down without moving)

If you have any idea on how to fix this or ideas on how to improve this, everything is welcome !

Thank you in advance !

Comment: It doesn't seem like it'd make a lot of sense to "backspace beyond the start of a line". Can you *backspace* output prior to the current line of input, too? If not, does backspacing beyond a line of input leave output intact and only affect previous input? How do you rationalise backspacing input that has already been processed? Do you *undo* the processing?

Comment: Oh. I see. I apologise for misunderstanding your question. I do have some ideas that might help...

Comment: The thing is that it shouldn't go to the next line. the whole "testtestest" text is one continuous string. As for backspacing prior to the current line of input, you can only _backspace_ output on the line of input, nothing before. Basically when you _backspace_ beyond a line of input, it deletes the output from the screen and reduces the counter. I don't really understand what you mean by _rationalizing_ backspacing input, could you explain a little? Also, what do you define as an input and output in my code ? For me they're both the same here... (although i'm pretty sure im wrong)

Comment: Your ideas are very welcome then :)

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that your idea sways from the usual CLI design. Perhaps GUI would be more sensible for this.

If you really wish to use the CLI, let's take a look at how you could model your application around CLI, without getting in the way too much. People who use the CLI might expect certain things of applications that run in the CLI:

1. A typical CLI has buffers that keep previous lines of input, and people who use the CLI are used to this. Hence, the "up" arrow is used a lot. This would be complicated to implement in your application, right?
2. CLI apps tend to return back to the shell fairly quickly, even if they run infinitely as a background process. Again, people who use the CLI are used to this. They might want to enter commands while your "twitter" is running, and might be tempted to close it if it's preventing them from doing so.
3. You've discovered the backspace problem, already.

How do you implement all of these features at once, without complicating your code-base too much? Split it into two applications:

1. A program to recieve messages. This program runs in the background, writing any recieved messages to the file indicated by `argv`. This way the user could create a named pipe to send the messages to. When the user wants to recieve and check messages, he/she can `cat messages` then go back to doing whatever it was before he/she decided to check messages without even switching windows. This program follows the same design principles as many tried-and-tested programs, such as apache and the likes which run in the background and log to files.
2. A program to send messages. This program sends the message found in `argv` and quits. You could have it communicate with the background app. That way, there's very little delay caused by network latency before the program terminates. Note that this also follows the same design principles as many standard command-line programs: `ls`, `dir`, `cd`, etc... It does it's job, then quits, allowing the CLI session to be used again. When the user wants to send a message, he/she can `send message ...`, then go back to what he/she was doing previously.

By splitting your design into two programs, you've met all three of those expectations without any cumbersome libraries such as ncurses or system-dependent hacks. The shell handles the up-arrow behaviour for you (or it doesn't, in which case the user probably won't care), the background process doesn't prevent the user from doing other work in the same console window, and the shell handles backspaces for you, so you don't need to handle that, either.

The only other option I see is using GUI or a library such as ncurses, which will give you the power to create the same functionality but using a much more complex solution, and less portability.

Comment: I've never used CLI design before (well at least being aware of it), and using different _applications_ sounds very interesting and promising ! Do you have any websites that might explain it in more details ? Even though this does not directly answer my question, it might solve my problem so thanks! I'll wait and see if anybody else has any alternatives

Comment: @blackjak231 You've never used a Linux bash shell, or Windows command prompt? This is what you're designing your software to run in... It's very important that you familiarise yourself with the console before designing software to run in the console. In addition, an understanding of the CLI will help you if your IDE ever breaks down. I presume you're targetting POSIX-compliant OSes. Here's a tutorial for [Windows](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr05/cos126/cmd-prompt.html) and here's one for [BASH on Linux/BSD](http://www.hypexr.org/bash_tutorial.php) to get you started.

Comment: Well yes, i know how to use the windows command prompt, but not wih many commands. I only code in C and display the result in the cmd prompt. As for Linux, i've never touched the bash shell :/ I'll look at the links you gave me, thanks a lot!